# What is this parser design pattern called? A parser using an array of structures containing keywords and function pointers?

Tags: c, parsing, design-patterns, terminology

I've seen parsers where the the handling of each keyword is controlled by an array of structures containing each keyword and function pointers to how to handle that keyword. What is this pattern called?

Rather than trying to include a vague example here, I'll just point you to my [project](https://github.com/dlundquist/HTTPS-SNI-Proxy/blob/config/src/config.c#L75).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds very much like [Table-Driven parsing](http://www.cs.uaf.edu/~cs631/notes/parse/node4.html), which is generally employed by [LR parsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LR_parser#Action_and_goto_tables).

Answer (score 0):

A symbol (keyword) table with procedural attachment?

Is this a linear table without any order?

I have to say I've never done that.  I have built *hash* tables containing keywords and action pointers.  Look up an identifier in the hash table; if hit, call the keyword routine.